# SwiftUI Charts: Adding Label To Bar Chart Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I am working in SwiftUI with the new Charts framework introduced in WWDC22 for iOS 16.

I want the value of each bar to be displayed inside the bar, but I don't see anyway in the Charts framework to do this. The best I can do is use a ZStack and try layering text on top of the chart, which works, but doesn't keep the text centered in the bar as the data changes.

Anyone discovered a way to do this natively in SwiftUI Charts?

Comment: Have a look at this: 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Charts
 and this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/charts/visualizing_your_app_s_data
 these will give you the answer to your question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The bars can be annotated by using an overlay position and a center alignment using this code:

```
.annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) { 
  // your Text or other overlay here
}
```

An example chart with the annotations.

[image]

The complete code that was used to create the chart is provided below for reference.

Chart code:

```
struct BarChart4: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center)  {
            Text("Basic Bar Chart")
                .font(.callout)
                .foregroundStyle(.secondary)
            
            Chart (BarData4.data) { shape in
                BarMark (
                    x: .value("Shape", shape.type),
                    y: .value("Count", shape.count)
                )
                .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                    Text("\(shape.count, format: .number.precision(.fractionLength(0)))")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sample Data:

```
struct BarData4 {
    static let data: [ShapeModel] = [
        .init(type: "Square",    count: 12),
        .init(type: "Heart",     count: 10),
        .init(type: "Rectangle", count: 21),
        .init(type: "Star",      count: 15),
        .init(type: "Circle",    count: 8),
        .init(type: "Triangle",  count: 6)
    ]
}
```

And the Data Model:

```
struct ShapeModel: Identifiable {
    var type: String
    var count: Double
    var id = UUID()
}
```

Comment: The annotation text will wrap to the "bounds" of the BarMark.  How to make it _not_ wrap?

Comment: Just found out a way is to make an invisible (width, height of 0) RectangleMark with the exact same `x` and `y` of the BarMark and then annotate that instead.